# how to get products for a attribute - magento

Tags: magento, attributes

I have created a attribute Fresh arrival with two values yes or no in dropdown and I am creating a block which is reading from a phtml file. How can I get all products which have fresh arrival set as yes while saving the product in phtml file.

Comment: if you find my answer helpful then accept my answer to help others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using collections

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code', true);
```

in $collection you will have an object with needed products. You cann loop over them to get each product

```
foreach ($collection as $_product){
    echo $_product->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can get attribute value from

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
           ->addAttributeToFilter($attributecode, 1);
$products = $_productCollection->getItems();
   foreach($products as $product)
   {
    echo $product->getName()
   }
```

`$attributecode` **is your attribute code**

Comment: thanks $attribute_value will going to have yes or no in my case i will have to loop over all products and check if values is set to yes, is there a way to get all products in a variable whose attribute value is set to yes?

Comment: i think you have to loop over there and put condition